# Why does Blender re-calculate lighting when you pan/zoom/rotate?

Tags: 3d-view

This isn't a urgent question, I'm just curious. Why does blender have to recalculate the lighting every time you pan/rotate/zoom in rendered view? The lighting itself is not changing, so why does it have to do that?

Comment: The lighting might not change, but how the surfaces are being seen form camera perspective can be different. For example, when looking at glossy surfaces the reflections will change as the point of view changes.

Comment: hmm, I guess that makes sense. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: One thing that is done for games is baking the lighting of the scene into the surfaces of the objects. Then you don't need to recalculate. Read: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/ note that baking doesn't work for all kinds of surfaces.